# JS variable issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a very simple js function to toggle div visibility, here's the working version:

```
function Toggle(obj) {   
    var state = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (state.style.display === 'block') {
        state.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        state.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Here obj represents the id of a div. Now, I have multiple divs on page, and want when user opens a new div, to have previously opened div closed. I tried to do it by modifying my function like this:

```
var prev_obj = 'empty';

 function Toggle(obj) {  
    var state = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (state.style.display === 'block') {
        state.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {

                if (prev_obj !== 'empty')
                {
        var prev_state = document.getElementById(prev_obj)
        prev_state.style.display = 'none';
                }       
        state.style.display = 'block';

                prev_obj = obj;
    }
}
```

I guess this is self explanatory to js wizards out there, so I'll just say, when I hard-code the value for prev_obj, it works, but when I don't it doesn't, and firebug shows that it's keeping the initial value ("empty")

Help appreciated as well as any other way to do this if you have it.

Comment: Can jQuery be used for the solution?

Comment: This code should work... are you sure that prev_obj is being declared global? For a quick test, try removing 'var' from the declaration of prev_obj. (this is not the type of thing that should be global though...)

Comment: How is the `Toggle` function being called?

Comment: @Thomas Langston: I love jQuery, but cannot apply it on this project, need to keep this ultra light weight.

Comment: @Hersheezy: I tried removing var, nothing changed

Comment: @box9: It's being called from anchor tag, by onclick="Toggle(div-id-here)"

Comment: @Freelancer, not sure if this was just because you were typing an example here, but you'd want single quotes for the div id: `onclick="Toggle('div-id-here')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, I suspect that the function is being called incorrectly as it looks like it should work.

On another note, you can simplify the logic a little, if you consider that what you want is the same as saying: "*close the previous div no matter what (including if it's the same as the current div), and only open the current div if it is different to the previous one*".

I'd also store the actual element in `prev_obj` instead of the ID, and set it to `null` initially. It'll make testing if there was a `prev_obj` easier, and also allows you to use the ID of "empty" if necessary (of course you probably won't, but just best practice).

```
var prev_obj = null;

function Toggle(id) { // Call it "id" to be clear it's not the actual object
   // Hide previous object if it exists
   if (prev_obj) prev_obj.style.display = 'none';

   // Show current object if it's the same as the previous one
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   if (obj !== prev_obj) {
      obj.style.display = 'block';
      prev_obj = obj;
   }
}
```

Make sure you call it by including single quotes around the id:

```
<div onclick="Toggle('div-id-here')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell where your problem is from the details provided.  You should be able to develop a solution with the tutorial linked below.  Personally I'd loop over all the divs, hide them all, and then show the current one instead of holding a reference to the last div.

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

Comment: Thanks for this resource. I'm fairly new to js, so sorry for asking, but how looping through 10 divs is better than just closing the specific div?

Comment: @Freelancer - I think it is not necessarily better, but just easier to conceptualise - especially if you come from the jQuery world, where you don't need to write a loop for this. So you end up with just two statements: one to hide all divs, the other to show one of them. It's harder to make a mistake that way, but no, not necessarily better.

Comment: @Freelancer  As @box9 said it is easier to conceptualize.  Reduced complexity is much more important than increased performance, except where testing indicates performance improvements are required.